# How to construct a matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Construct a matrix $A$ such that $A^2\ne 0$ but $A^3=0$.

I need your help to find $A$. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try first an easier but related problem: Construct a matrix $A\neq 0$ such that $A^2=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\text{Let} \;\;\;A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\text{Then} \;\;\;\; A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \neq \bf 0$$

$$\text{But} \;\;\;\; \;A^3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \bf 0$$

Comment: Also, it is easy to see that this provides a general approach of any nxn, with a set of parameters as opposed to numbers. +1

Comment: For my precious +

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to @Julian's comment, take $A=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1\\
  0&0
\end{pmatrix}$, Or $A=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 &1 &0 
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Nice examples too my friend! +1

Comment: How did your lecture go, my friend? ;-)

Comment: It's done good as I had expected. Lobachevsky's sprite was there to protect me. :D

Comment: @BabakS.:+▒▒▓▓███B█e█s█t██A█n█s█w█e█r███▓▒▒+

Comment: @flashdesign2550: Thanks. This just a small attempt. That is it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Generally, when you have a zero matrix with the line above the diagonal filled by zeros, you have that:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & \dots &0&0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0&0\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
  0&0&0&\dots&1&0\\
  0 & 0 &0 &\dots &0 & 1\\
 0&0&0&\dots&0&0
 \end{matrix}\right)^2=\left(\begin{matrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 &0&\dots &0&0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0  &1&\dots & 0&0\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots\\
  0&0&0&0&\dots&0&1\\
  0&0&0&0&\dots&0&0\\
  0&0&0&0&\dots&0&0
 \end{matrix}\right)$$

Basically, the diagonal of ones moves up a line, if you make the do $A^3$, then the line of ones will move up another line (try it with a 3x3 matrix). So seeting it up properly, you can make it vanish to zero when you want.